# What are the benefits of proper scoping?

Tags: c#, scope

So yeah, the question basically says it all. What do you gain when you ensure that private members / methods / whatever are marked private (or protected, or public, or internal, etc) appropriately?

I mean, of course I could just go and mark all my methods as public and everything should still work fine. Of course, if we'd talk about good programming practice (which I am a solid advocate of, by the way ), I'd mark a method as private if it should be marked as such, no questions asked.

But let's set aside good programming practice, and just look at this in terms of actual quantitative gain. What do I get for proper scoping of my methods, members, classes, etc.?

I'm thinking that this would most generally translate to performance gains, but I'd appreciate it if someone could provide more detail about it.

*(For purposes of this question, I'm thinking more along C#.NET, but hey, feel free to provide answers on whatever language / framework you deem fit.)*

**EDIT**: Most pointed out that this doesn't lead to performance gain, and yeah, thinking back, I don't even know why I thought that. Lack of coffee probably.

In any case, any good programmer should know about how proper scopes (1) help your code maintenance / (2) control the proper use of your library / app / package; I was kinda curious as to whether or not there was any other benefit you get from it that's not apparently obvious outright. Based on the answers below, it looks like it basically sums up to just those two things most importantly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Performance has absolutely nothing to do with the visibility of methods. Virtual methods have some overhead, but that's not why we scope. It has to do with maintenance of code. Your public methods are the API to your class or library. You as a class designer want to provide some guarantee to the outside world that future changes aren't going to break other peoples code. By marking some methods private, you take away the ability for users to depend on certain implementations which allows you freedom to change that implementation at will.

Even languages that don't have visibility modifiers, like python, have conventions for marking methods as internal and subject to change. By prefixing the method with an _underscore(), you're signalling to the outside world that if you use that method, you do so at your own risk, as it can change at any time.

On the other hand, public methods are an explicit entry way into your code. Every effort should go towards making public methods backward compatible to avoid the pitfalls I described above.

Answer (score 5):

By better encapsulation, you provide a better API.  Only methods / properties that are of interest of the user of your class are available : visible.
Next to that, you ensure that certain variables that should not be called / modified, cannot be called/modified.

That's the most important thing.  Why do you think this would lead to performance gains ?

Comment: Nah, just typing that question out, it was the first thing that came to mind. Doubling back now, I see how skewed that was. But in any case, I was more of interested in whatever benefits proper scoping gave. Of course, there's always easier maintenance, proper access, but I was kinda curious if there was something else besides all that that helped make the argument for proper scopes.

Answer (score 5):

As I see you gain two important features from proper scoping. You API is reduced in size and clearly focused on the task at hand.

Second, you get a less brittle implementation as you are free to change implementation details without altering the exposed API.

I cannot see how accessibility modifiers would affect performance in any way.

Answer (score 2):

There are mainly two types of methods/properties.

1. That are helpful to perform a task to whoever consumes it. (Recommended Scope: `Public`)
2. That are helpful to the above methods to get their task done. (Recommended Scope: `Private` or `Protected`)

`Type 1` methods are the only methods that any client code requires and does not need any other method. This avoids confusion, keeps things simple and prevents client code to do something wrong.

`Type 2` methods are methods into which Type 1 methods are divided. They help Type 1 methods to complete their task and still allow them to be simple, concise, less complex and more readable. They are not really needed for client code but just the class/module itself.

A fair example would be of a car. What you have is a gas pedal, brakes, gearbox, etc. You don't have an interface to minor details for what is under the hood. That is for the mechanic.

Answer (score 2):

In C# programming, it helps to make sure that your API/classes/methods/members are **"easy to use correctly and difficult to use incorrectly"**.